# How to choose case from array list in a different method

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement

I am currently making a hang man game in java, and I have the list of words organized by difficulty in one method and then in another method, i have an if statement asking which difficulty the user would like to play on. How would i go about doing this? My code is as follows:

```
public static int word(){
 String words[] = new String[26];
    switch(diff){
    case 1:
      words[0] = "cat";
      words[1] = "dog";
      words[2] = "book";          
      words[3] = "breakfeast";          
      words[4] = "telephone";          
      words[5] = "mixture";          
      words[6] = "music";          
      words[7] = "animal";          
      words[8] = "school";          
      words[9] = "plant";          
      words[10] = "pen";          
      words[11] = "pencil";          
      words[12] = "paper";          
      words[13] = "note";          
      words[14] = "fog";          
      words[15] = "smoke";        
      words[16] = "bake";          
      words[17] = "alone";          
      words[18] = "drive";          
      words[19] = "town";          
      words[20] = "city";          
      words[21] = "sunny";          
      words[22] = "shine";          
      words[23] = "polish";          
      words[24] = "cap";          
      words[25] = "hat";

      break;
    case 2:
      words[0] = "president";
      words[1] = "exclamation";          
      words[2] = "statement";          
      words[3] = "television";          
      words[4] = "physics";          
      words[5] = "algebra";          
      words[6] = "geometry";          
      words[7] = "difficult";          
      words[8] = "extreme";          
      words[9] = "procedure";          
      words[10] = "ship";          
      words[11] = "soldier";          
      words[12] = "lunch";          
      words[13] = "hockey";          
      words[14] = "tennis";          
      words[15] = "soccer";          
      words[16] = "football";          
      words[17] = "basketball";          
      words[18] = "bias";          
      words[19] = "magazine";          
      words[20] = "computer";          
      words[21] = "internet";          
      words[22] = "allegedly";          
      words[23] = "system";          
      words[24] = "unison";          
      words[25] = "excited";         
      break;
    case 3:
      words[0] = "amalgamation";          
      words[1] = "proclomation";          
      words[2] = "establishment";          
      words[3] = "rehabilitation";          
      words[4] = "rhinoceros";          
      words[5] = "velociraptor";         
      words[6] = "declaration";         
      words[7] = "announcement";          
      words[8] = "binomial";          
      words[9] = "polynomial";          
      words[10] = "congregation";          
      words[11] = "obligation";          
      words[12] = "structure";          
      words[13] = "description";          
      words[14] = "perscription";          
      words[15] = "subscribe";          
      words[16] = "address";          
      words[17] = "township";          
      words[18] = "mischievous";          
      words[19] = "bewildered";          
      words[20] = "accusation";          
      words[21] = "designation";          
      words[22] = "disgusting";          
      words[23] = "prolonged";          
      words[24] = "restoration";          
      words[25] = "regeneration";          
  }

int i = words.length;

Random rng = new Random();     //This block of code chooses random word from array list
int choice = rng.nextInt(words.length); //Varible storing random word
String wd = words[choice];
out.println(wd);
}



public static int gameStart(){
    Scanner qwe = new Scanner(in);
    out.println("Welcome to my Hang Man game!\n");
    out.println("What difficulty would you like to play on?\t1-3");
    int diff = qwe.nextInt();

    if (diff == 1){
        //not sure what would go here
    }
    else if (diff == 2){
        //not sure what would go here
    }
    else{
        //not sure what would go here
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Store words per each difficulty in a separate text file.
2. Create a method `String[] getWords(int difficulty)` that would return you a list of words loaded from a file for given difficulty.
3. Don't mix code dealing with different aspects of your program in one method - like you did in `word()` method. Creating a list of words, choosing random word and displaying it on screen sounds like 3 different aspects. That means roughly 3 methods.

Comment: + 1 for the hint to separate the application logic from the data.

Comment: ok, So say i made 3 different text files named words1, words2, and words3. In the IF statement, if the user enters '1' it would use the text file named words1 and choose a random word from that list. How would i do that?
Also, in the text files, should every word be on a new line?

Comment: In `getWords()` you need an iff that will choose the right file to read from. Then you need to get all the words from that file. Yes, I would say a work per line if the easiest layout for that purpose.

Comment: These three suggestions are reasonably good suggestions, but they don't answer the question of how to receive the random word back.  The real problem was that the word was being printed to the screen, and there is no way to pass the difficulty variable into the method with the case statement.

Comment: @AgilePro arguably we're here not only to provide ready solution, but to guide people to come to the correct solution on their own. Especially if the problem seems to be a result of bad code in the first place.

Comment: How do i make the array read from a text file? I can't figure it out.
And thank you so much to everyone trying to help me

Answer (score 0):

You need a parameter on that `word()` method, and you need to return the words from that method as a string (not an int).  The rest of the routine (case statement and the random word selection) are OK, so I did not duplicate that below.  Maybe something like this:

```
public static String word(int diff) {
    ....
    return wd;
}
```

Then down where you have the if block, you don't need an if block, just pass the difficulty into the routine.  Something like:

```
String myWord = word(diff);
```